# how to load font family from server using css2

Tags: css

I want to load font from server using css2. I want to keep font on server.I don't want to use CSS3 as not all the browser support it so how can I do that using css2?

```
@font-face
```

Comment: If you have any browser compatibility issues, let us know. This question is seriously absurd! What are you trying to ask?

Comment: please improve this question..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lucida_sans_unicoderegular';
    src: url('font/lsansuni-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/lsansuni-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/lsansuni-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/lsansuni-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/lsansuni-webfont.svg#lucida_sans_unicoderegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
#menu {
    font-family: 'lucida_sans_unicoderegular',Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
</style>
```

lsansuni-webfont.eot ,lsansuni-webfont.wof,.. Place this files in font folder

Use this generator to create @fontface

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator is simple way, dont want to do with your own

Answer (score 1):

#### [What is it?](http://www.font-face.com/)

`@font-face` is a css rule which allows you to download a particular font from your server to render a webpage if the user hasn't got that font installed. This means that web designers will no longer have to adhere to a particular set of "web safe" fonts that the user has pre-installed on their computer.

#### [How to use:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face)

#### Syntax

```
@font-face {
  font-family: <a-remote-font-name>;
  src: <source> [,<source>]*;
  [font-weight: <weight>];
  [font-style: <style>];
}
```

#### Example

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyHelvetica;
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Bold"),
  local("HelveticaNeue-Bold"),
  url(MgOpenModernaBold.ttf);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

#### Compatibility:

It is supported by IE 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Firefox, Chrome.